# Optimizing video game AI for coordinated throwing

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search, path-finding

I'm currently working on implementing the AI for a tile-based video game. There are multiple enemies, which can each move a single tile per turn. These enemies can also throw balls to each other any distance within a straight line, but the throwing only works when there is an enemy ready to catch the object. Given these conditions, how can we find the shortest sequence of coordinated moves for one enemy A to throw a ball to another enemy B?

Essentially, we want to move enemy A and enemy B so that they end up within a straight line of each other.

My first and very rough idea is to use a basic BFS and spread outwards from enemy A, one tile at a time. At each step of the BFS, we then note down all the tiles which can be thrown to from the current point P (basically just fanning outwards from point P in straight lines. I could also first calculate these and save them in a table called Throwable for memoization). We record the distance from enemy B to those throwable tiles. At the end of the BFS, we then take the point such that (distance from enemy A to point P) + (distance from enemy B to Throwable[P]) is minimized.

However, this seems like a very inefficient and brute-force approach. Is there some more efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: Is it impossible that decide which line should be used, at first time? (For example, considering the lines from the initial position of A, is it possible that the line closest to B is a candidate?)

Comment: If such thinking is possible, I think that, the problem can be considered as : "the point closest to B, on the candidate line" and "B" move closer to each other. (Of course, the movement of the point is caused by the movement of A.)